# Dart equivalent of \n

Tags: newline, dart

Is there a Dart equivalent to C++'s "\n"?

In the following example:

```
for(int j=0;j<readLines.length;j++)
{
    outputFile.writeAsStringSync(readLines[j], mode: FileMode.APPEND);
}
```

I would like to have the text that's in "readLines[j]" in separate lines. How could this be done?

For example:

readLines is a List of Strings, and it contains: "Hey my name is Cheshie", and "Thanks guys for trying to help".

In the code above, I am trying to write the content of the list into a file, using "outputFile", and I would like it to be written as follows:

*Hey my name is Cheshie*

*Thanks guys for trying to help*

That is, every readLines[j] should be written in a separate line.

Thanks.

The code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void func (String foldername)
{
  Directory thisFolder = new Directory (foldername);

  List<File> files = thisFolder.listSync(recursive:false);
  int number=1;
  String oldContent='';
  String newContent='';
  String concatenate='';
  String name='';
  int nameStart;
  int nameLength;
  for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
  {
    if (files[i].name.endsWith('.in'))
    {
      oldContent=files[i].readAsStringSync(Encoding.UTF_8);
      newContent=number.toString();

      var Strings=[newContent, oldContent];
      concatenate=Strings.join();

      files[i].writeAsStringSync(concatenate);
      number++;
    }
```

// =====================***Here begins the relevant part***==================

```
    nameLength=files[i].name.length;
    nameStart=files[i].name.lastIndexOf('\\', nameLength);
    name=files[i].name.slice(nameStart+1, nameLength);
    if (name.compareTo('hello.in')==0)
    {
      File outputFile=new File('hello.out');
      if (outputFile.existsSync())
      {
        outputFile.deleteSync();
      }
      outputFile.createSync();
      List<String> readLines=files[i].readAsLinesSync(Encoding.UTF_8);
      for(int j=0;j<readLines.length;j++)
      {
        outputFile.writeAsStringSync('$readLines[j]\n', mode: FileMode.APPEND); 
        //outputFile.writeAsStringSync('\n', mode: FileMode.APPEND); 
        //  TODO:   figure out how to get to the next line.

        if (readLines[j].contains('you'))
          print(readLines[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}


void main ()
{
  func('In files');
  print('the end!');
}
```

Answer (score 17):

`\n` is not C++ specific, you can just add it to the end of your string before writing it to the file. So, use something like

```dart
outputFile.writeAsStringSync('${readLines[j]}\n', mode: FileMode.APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure? I tried using the \n as you said but it reacted oddly: It wrote _all_ of the contents of 'readLines' into 'outputFile' j times, with the characters '[j],' (including the comma) at the end of each line. So yes, it did jump to the next line, but it was supposed to only print the string in the 'j'th place each time. How did that happen...? Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like you did '$readLines[j]\n' and not '${readLines[j]}\n'. The curly braces make a big difference there.

Comment: No... with the curly brackets there is no difference in the output file (the text is written without moving to the next line). :(

Comment: are you absolutely sure you aren't doing a '${readLines}[j]' rather than '${readLines[j]}'.

Comment: I'm confused... I tried now and it writes to the file as usual, without moving to the next line. I even tried: for(int j=0;j<readLines.length;j++)
      {
        outputFile.writeAsStringSync('${readLines[j]}\n', mode: FileMode.APPEND);
        outputFile.writeAsStringSync('\n', mode: FileMode.APPEND);  } But it's still all in the same line... Why is it ignoring the '\n'?

Answer (score 6):

In current version it works.

```
void main() {
  print('word\nsecondword');
}
```

Console:

```
word
secondword
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

Dart 3.2.0 helpfully [introduced](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#dartio-1) `Platform.lineTerminator` which can be used to get the terminator appropriate to the OS. Docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform/lineTerminator.html).

Answer (score 2):

What are the contents of `readLines[j]` ? A bunch of words?

Assuming something like this:

```
var readLines = [
  'Dart is fun',
  'It is easy to learn'
];
```

And assuming you want to output the following:

```
Dart
is
fun
It
is
easy
to
learn
```

Try this:

```
for (String line in readLines) {
  String split = line.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\s+'), '\n');
  outputFile.writeAsStringSync(split, mode: FileMode.APPEND);
}
```

Comment: readLines[j] is a bunch of words, but I want the output to be: "Dart is fun" and in the next line: "It is easy to learn". So I can't replace the spaces with a \n.  What JustDanyul suggested looks the the right direction for the answer, only it doesn't work...

Comment: Chesie, can you update your question with an example of the input and an example of the output you expect? That way I can be sure to help you exactly :)

Comment: It's more clear, but I think you need to add the entire app's code. I'm reading the comments and I think there's some details missing. Can you paste the entire script?

Comment: `\n` generate LineFeed only in Ubuntu, but `\n` generate CarriageReturn + LineFeed in Windows. I think we might need something like `Platform.NewlineChar`

Comment: @sunglim can you please file a feature request here: http://dartbug.com/new thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not working on Windows because you are using just `\n` that is the Line Feed (LF) char. To get a new line in Windows you need to use `\r\n` for Carriage Return + Line Feed (CRLF).

For more information about this, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

I have seen some differences between Windows 10 and older versions. I don't know if it has todo with Windows itself or with the way Dart compiles for each version. It would need more debug to understand...

Answer (score 0):

The below line worked for me:

```
file.writeAsStringSync('$data\r', mode: FileMode.append);
```

here `data` is string you have to write and `\r` will move cursor to next line.