# How to get platform-dependent line separator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character) question (java), how can I get the platform-dependent line separator in Flutter?

I tried the `Platform` class but it doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no "dart-built-in way" of doing it, you can use an extension, something like:

```
import 'dart:io';

extension PlatformExtension on Platform {
  String get lineSeparator => Platform.isWindows
      ? '\r\n'
      : Platform.isMacOS
          ? '\r'
          : Platform.isLinux
              ? '\n'
              : '\n';
}
```

Then it can be used as:

```
String s = Platform().lineSeparator;
```

#### Update:

As jamesdlin suggested in the comment, `LineSplitter` can also come in handy when reading from text files.

Comment: Modern macOS is a Unix-based OS and uses LF (`\n`) as a line separator.  Only the old, "classic" MacOS (9 and earlier) used CR (`\r`).  For modern platforms, `Platform.isWindows ? '\r\n' : '\n'` should be sufficient.  Also, most of the time you shouldn't even care what the line separator is.

Comment: Whoops, I was wrong about the last part of what I wrote.  You normally shouldn't care about the line separator for reading (because you should use [`LineSplitter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html)), but I don't think there's any automatic newline conversion for writes.

Comment: @jamesdlin didn't know about LineSplitter, in this case I will definitely use it for reading instead, thx

Comment: Dart 3.2.0 -> you can now use `Platform.lineTerminator`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77295824/5047737